# longtabu from within newenvironment

Tags: environments, tabu, longtabu

I'm trying to use a longtabu environment as a replacement for a tabularx environment that I was using. When I try to compile this example, I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.26       \end{steplist}
```

The example that I'm trying to compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcounter{StepListCounter}
\newenvironment{steplist} {
    \renewcommand\item[2]{%
        \\[\medskipamount]
        \noindent
        \stepcounter{StepListCounter}
        {\textbf{\arabic{StepListCounter}}} & ##1 & &
        \parbox[c]{1em}{##2} \\
    }

    \setcounter{StepListCounter}{0}
    \longtabu to \linewidth {l X c X}
    %\tabularx{\linewidth}{l X c X}
} {
    \endlongtabu
    %\endtabularx
    \\[\medskipamount]
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{steplist}
  \end{steplist}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong here? When I swap `tabu` in for `longtabu`, it works perfect.

Comment: Why `\renewcommand{\item}`?

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence the OP wants a list-like markup with a table based implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tabularx` is a horizontal mode construct so you can have `\\`after it but `longtable` is a vertical mode construct so you can not follow it by `\\`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcounter{StepListCounter}
\newenvironment{steplist} {
    \renewcommand\item[2]{%
        \\[\medskipamount]
        \noindent
        \stepcounter{StepListCounter}
        {\textbf{\arabic{StepListCounter}}} & ##1 & &
        \parbox[c]{1em}{##2} \\
    }

    \setcounter{StepListCounter}{0}
    \longtabu to \linewidth {l X c X}
    %\tabularx{\linewidth}{l X c X}
} {
    \endlongtabu
    %\endtabularx
    \medskip
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{steplist}
  \end{steplist}
\end{document}
```